How can I get the audio listener to follow AR/VR headset? Audio Listener is NOT moving with headset
I’m currently developing for the Apple Vision Pro, but my buddy seems to run into a similar issue on the meta-quest pro as well; I have the audio listener attached to the main XR camera in the Unity editor and even though the headset moves, the audio listener stays at the origin or location where I started the app, therefore when a user hears audio from a game object they hear it with respect to the location where they started the app NOT their current location/location of the headset in physical space.
I’ve tried circumventing the issue by attaching an empty child game object to the main camera and placing the audio source on that child object so it follows the camera/headset coordinates with no luck. I’ve also printed out the coordinates on the UI using text mesh pro and I can assure you the camera/headset coordinates are indeed changing with respect to the movement of the headset, but the audio listener still sounds like it’s coming from the origin point, in other words, the location where I started the application so it seems fixed. Attached is a screenshot of my object hierarchy in the Unity editor and the child object with the audio listener component attached to it.
It’s worth noting that I am using ARFoundation, the XR interaction kit packages, and I am developing an ‘unbounded’ app for the Apple Vision Pro. Thank you



I see AudioObject 1 in your hierarchy. By any chance, isn't that object an AudioListener too? You should only have a single AudioListener in your scene.
